# Android HTTP POST AUTHENTICATION

Tags: android, android-studio, http-post

please read through the code,bear with me.There is a web page mentioned inside the code where I want to do authorization with post. have done this

`httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();`

```
            httpPost=new HttpPost("http://52.77.???.???/???????/??");

            //UN and PW value mentioned no worry
            String auth = "Basic "
                    + Base64.encodeToString(
                    ( UN+ ":" + PW).getBytes(),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP);
            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization",auth);

            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("vendorId",null);
                jsonObject.put("userName",UN);
                jsonObject.put("password",PW);
                StringEntity stringEntity=new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
                new getInfo().execute();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

}
public class getInfo extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
            Log.d("reponse",httpEntity.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

}

//but everytime connection failed,means no reponse.I have tried with all code.What am I missing?

Comment: post the error message or exception you see

Comment: no error,just no response,the server wants username and password as authentication and some data wrapped up as json and send

Comment: Have you tried accessing the server from a browser or other app on the same device?